# Apple Business Chat integration with iMessage Extension

Tags: ios, imessage, imessage-extension

I'm trying to send an iMessage extension with Apple's new Business chat but it's asking for the app ID from the iTunes store. Is there any way to test this with a custom app that has not been submitted for review yet?

Comment: are you trying to received message in iMessage extension from apple business chat ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 "interactiveData": {
        "appId": 123456789,
        "appName": "Package Delivery",
        "URL": "<...>",
        "bid": "com.apple.messages.MSMessageExtensionBalloonPlugin:<...>",
        "sessionIdentifier": "{{uuid}}",
        "receivedMessage": {
            "title": "WWDC Goodies",
            "subtitle": "Scheduled for delivery - Today",
            "secondarySubtitle": "",
            "tertiarySubtitle": "",
            "imageTitle": "",
            "imageSubtitle": ""
        },
        "useLiveLayout": true
    },
    "attachments": [

    ]
```

There are 2 parameters that are responsible for appID to invoke this features: **appId** and **bid**.
Probably, when we tested this feature, we've just built an app, signed it with a certificate and upload it to an iPhone through Xcode and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the app id by adding a new app to "My Apps" in iTunes Connect. Don't submit it for review if you just need it for testing.